# How to enable slow genie effect in macOS 10.13 High Sierra?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, window-manager

In the past, we can hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and press minimize button to get slow genie effect. But in macOS 10.13 High Sierra, I can't use this trick anymore. How to enable this feature?

Comment: Same with other animations like Widgets.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Thanks to @etaionshrd on Reddit we have this Terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock slow-motion-allowed -bool true && killall Dock
```

If it doesn't work, try copy-pasting it. There is no auto-correct in Terminal and spelling counts. Works for me macOS 10.13.2 High Sierra.

https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/6jeefp/in_the_latest_high_sierra_beta_a_small_relic_from/#t1_dmpcle3

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. I've noticed some interesting behavior: it seems to work fine for almost everything (minimizing, Mission Control, show desktop, Dashboard), *except* Dashboard when using the actual Dashboard key rather than F12. It's quite possible this is also specific to my computer (tMBP) due to some strange quirk.

Comment: Wohoo!! It works! Thanks to you and @etaionshrd on Reddit. :D

Comment: @JMY1000 that should be the case. It is slow motion animation not necessarily only for dock (although that is what the command implies)

Comment: @cmarangu Yup, just found it strange it didn't always work for the dashboard.

Comment: Why are so many people voting up the answer and not the question?

Comment: @JMY1000 That's because the dashboard key is intercepted by macOS and to launch the Dashboard app, rather than going through Dock.

Comment: @saagarjha I wouldn't have been so surprised if it wasn't for the fact that the Dashboard key used to behave differently and allow the slowdown. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Comparing across different computers so it's hard to say

Comment: This method works as of macOS 10.14 Mojave Beta (18A293u)

Comment: @JeevanTakhar glad to hear!

Comment: @JMY1000 oh it didn't always work for dashboard? Well I guess it was a feature they snuck in then. Also, anyone interested in this might be interested in the hidden 'suck' minimize effect

Comment: It appears to work on Dashboard regardless

Comment: The "Suck" minimise effect is what is used when removing items from Dashboard (hold down Option⌥ while hovering over a widget)

Comment: Why not recommend copy/paste in the first place? There is *absolutely no reason* to type this command yourself. Just copy and paste.

Comment: @ell I dont get what you're asking but I was just annoyed because if you look at the reddit there was this one guy who posted it and hardly anybody noticed. The one guy who did reply (other than me) said that it "didnt work" so I just wanted to emphasize to copy paste if it "doesn't work"

Comment: Works on both 10.13.x and 10.4. Question is: why was it hidden away? and more important: how can one explore available "defaults" for all Mac components, even those that are NOT set (and thus cannot be enlisted) ???

Comment: The is no easy way, but it helps if you’re poking around for other unrelated functionality and see a call to one of Apple’s wrappers for `CFPreferencesCopyAppValue`.

Comment: @saagarjha my point exactly. The only people who understand this stuf are those who work, _inside_ apple. I have been recreational programmer for 7-8 years, does literally nothing for my resume. As soon as I try to learn something new like raytracing I ama noob all over again. All these people who spend their time readig long paragraphs in the docs are the ones who go places. Paragraphs were written to be read. Thus concludes my subjective analysis, thesis remains in question.

Answer (score 2):

I think they set this feature disabled by default after 10 plus years, what a shame.